# Pandoc update fails due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, pandoc

I am trying to update pandoc on ubuntu 14.04 but it is failing due to unresolved dependencies:

```
leonardo@ICI-LAS:~$ sudo cabal update 
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org

ICI-LAS:~$ sudo cabal install pandoc pandoc-citeproc
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: pandoc-1.15.2.1
trying: pandoc-1.15.2.1:-old-locale
trying: pandoc-1.15.2.1:+network-uri
trying: network-2.6.0.2/installed-f92...
rejecting: unix-2.6.0.1/installed-808... (conflict: unix =>
time==1.4.0.1/installed-11d..., pandoc-1.15.2.1:old-locale => time>=1.5 &&
<1.6)
rejecting: unix-2.7.1.0, 2.7.0.1, 2.7.0.0, 2.6.0.1, 2.6.0.0, 2.5.1.1, 2.5.1.0,
2.5.0.0, 2.4.2.0, 2.4.1.0, 2.4.0.2, 2.4.0.1, 2.4.0.0, 2.3.2.0, 2.3.1.0,
2.3.0.0, 2.2.0.0, 2.0 (conflict: network => unix==2.6.0.1/installed-808...)

ICI-LAS:~$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3

ICI-LAS:~$ cabal  --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Is using [stackage](http://www.stackage.org/) even an option?

Comment: I recommend stackage as well. The [3.16](http://www.stackage.org/lts-3.16) release contains [pandoc 1.15.2.1](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.16/). And since it's stackage it's guaranteed to compile, whereas it seems like either the latest pandoc package is broken or your global package database is entering dependency hell.

Comment: Ok, I will try, thanks!